# PowerXpress error with Driver Catalyst. How can I fix it?

Tags: xorg, ati, configuration, fglrx, radeon

I have install Ubuntu 11.10 64bit on my [Hp Dv6-3150el](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?docname=c02675433&lc=en&cc=uk&destPage=document&dlc=en).
My Notebook has two graphics cards:

```
lspci | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: 
 Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 02)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: 
 ATI Technologies Inc Madison [AMD Radeon HD 5000M Series]
```

I tried to install the proprietary graphics drivers ''fglrx'' available in "Additional Drivers", which does not give me 3D graphics acceleration (and I can't install those post-release).

Then I can try to download and install from the website (I tried the version that Catalyst 11.8 11.12).

The installation goes perfectly (I followed this [guide](http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Ubuntu_Oneiric_Installation_Guide) and others), except that when I configure Xorg.conf file:

```
sudo aticonfig --initial
PowerXpress error: Cannot stat '/usr/lib64/fglrx': No such file or directory
Failed to initialize libglx for discrete GPU
```

Answer (score 1):

What I did was copy the /usr/lib/fglrx folder to /usr/lib64/fglrx:

```
sudo cp /usr/lib/fglrx /usr/lib64/fglrx
```

After restarting the XServer I was able to open AMD Control Panel and choose between dGPU and iGPU.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to make a symbolic link between /urs/lib64 and /usr/lib
so it would be

```
ln -s /usr/lib /usr/lib64
```

But I'm not sure that will solve your issues. After running aticonfig and restarting my computer, I got a black screen.

Answer (score 0):

I've used this forum post with success: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1930450

my lspci displays:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI Whistler [AMD Radeon HD 6600M Series] (rev ff)
```

however there is a difference between Radeon 5xxx and Radeon 6xxx devices.